# complementary transistor pair npn/pnp in the Kapustinsky circuit

Tags: transistors, npn

I need to create an old circuit that reproduces fast impulsion, the Kapustinsky circuit (see the picture).
This circuit is 33 years old, and a transistor (or equivalent) does not exist anymore, the PNP RF transistor [BFT92](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BFT92.pdf), which as a transition speed of 5GHz.
As described in the article 10.1016/0168-9002(85)90622-9, it's in a complementary pair transistor with a NPN [BFR93](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BFR93A.pdf), which is not a Darlington or Sziklai transistor (Am I right?).
I have two questions:

- I don't fully understand what the pair does exactly
- Is it possible to replace the PNP transistor, and how?

Thanks for your help[image]

Comment: There is no power source and no output terminal.

Comment: @Barry:  The negative power connection is missing.  It goes to the cathode of the LED.  There is no output.  The point of the circuit is to generate light pulses used to calibrate scintillation detectors in things like neutrino detection experiments.

Comment: This is going to sound a bit mean, but do a bit more searching.  I found references in scientific papers that mention that the combination of PNP and NPN transistors forms a sort of thyristor.  Sort of an extremely fast SCR.

Comment: Proper replacements would probably require going back to Kapustinki's original work and finding the requirements he used to choose those two transistors.

Comment: If you need to build just one (or a few) of these things, I find the transistors available in small numbers on ebay and from ham radio suppliers.

Comment: @JRE It is indeed wired as an SCR (I am old enough to remember doing discrete versions). Rather than driving the gate (which is at the base of the PNP / collector of the NPN) it pulls down the cathode with the gate pinned at ground. achieving SCR action. The power clearly comes from the source pulse. The current decays quickly below sustaining and then turns off.

Comment: @PeterSmith:  The papers I mention all have to do with building and using the circuit for its intended use (scintillation calibration) rather than in general about the transistor combination.  None of them goes into great detail about the selection of the transistors, although they do spend lots of words describing the effects of various capacitors, inductors, and LEDs on the pulse width and shape.

Comment: On a side note, I found it quite funny that one manufacturer of RF transistors now classifies 5GHz as "slow."

Comment: Some people use the 2N2369 "avalance" NPN for sub-1-nanosecond pulse generation.

Comment: NTE2403 is a rare, but available, equivalent.

Comment: @JRE right, that's exactly the purpose, neutrino experiment. That's right that I could find out that it's a SCR. I looked for, I think it's due to my lack of experience :s Anyway your answers are very useful, thanks.
I'll post what I'll do as answer to my question, thanks you all.